# Hover menu problems after moving main menu

Tags: html, css

```css
#header {
  height: 108px;
  width: 1140px;
  background-color: #faa220;
  position: relative;
}

#Logo2 {
  height: 108px;
  float: left;

}

#header links {
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #faa220;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 215px;
}

.container a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  }

.container a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #faa220;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #faa220;
  min-width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #faa220;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
    <div id="header">
    <img src="../JPEG/i2i logo 2.jpg" align="left" id="Logo2" />
    <div id="container">
      <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="index.html"><button class="dropbtn">Home</button></a>
        </div><!--dropdown close div-->
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="about.html"><button class="dropbtn">About Us</button></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="bio.html">Bio</a>
                <a href="news.html">News</a>
                <a href="partners.html">Partners</a>
            </div><!--dropdown-content close div-->
        </div><!--dropdown close div-->
        <div class="dropdown">  
            <a href="awards.html"><button class="dropbtn">Awards/Certifications</button></a>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="services.html"><button class="dropbtn">Services</button></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="solar.html">Solar</a>
                <a href="water.html">Water</a>
                <a href="housing.html">Housing</a>
                <a href="training.html">Training</a>
                <a href="broadband.html">Broadband</a>
            </div><!--dropdown-content close div-->
        </div><!--dropdown close div-->
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="help.html"><button class="dropbtn">How You Can Help</button></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="donate.html">Donate</a>
                <a href="volunteer.html">Volunteer</a>
                <a href="intern.html">Intern</a>
            </div><!--dropdown-content close div-->
        </div><!--dropdown close div-->
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="contact.html"><button class="dropbtn">Contact</button></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="email.html">Email</a>
                <a href="faqs.html">FAQS</a>
                <a href="newsletter.html">Newsletter</a>
            </div><!--dropdown-content-->
        </div><!--dropdown close div-->
    </div><!--container close div-->
```

I'm having problems with a hover menu after I moved the main menu. The div it's in is bigger than the menu div because of a logo. When I first coded the menu it was at the top of the div and the hover menu showed fine.

I moved the menu div to the bottom of the parent div using position absolute and relative, setting the bottom to 0 and right 215px. After that the hover menu started overlapping on the main menu. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I suggest adding a JSfiddle or code pen so people could better see what you are trying to accomplish. I took a quick look at your code and the menu has a lot of floats as well as absolute positioning which is causing your menu to be a mess.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make the Logo adapt to `headers` height:

```
#logo2 {

  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 108px;

}
```

You have set the menu container to an absolute position, I had make it inline, so it does not stays over the logo:
- So remove the `position: absolute;` from the `#container`, and add following: `line-height: 108px;`, to center the menu vertically.

In order to make the logo slightly smaller than the header itself, at same time centering it, I've added following to the #logo:

```
max-height: 70px;
margin: 19px 10px 19px 10px;
```

```css
#header {
  height: 108px;
  width: 1140px;
  background-color: #faa220;
  position: relative;
}

#Logo2 {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 70px;
  margin: 19px 10px 19px 10px;
}

#header links {
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #faa220;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 215px;
  line-height: 108px;
}

.container a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #faa220;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #faa220;
  min-width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #faa220;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ce/Coca-Cola_logo.svg/1200px-Coca-Cola_logo.svg.png" align="left" id="Logo2" />
  <div id="container">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a href="index.html"><button class="dropbtn">Home</button></a>
    </div>
    <!--dropdown close div-->
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a href="about.html"><button class="dropbtn">About Us</button></a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="bio.html">Bio</a>
        <a href="news.html">News</a>
        <a href="partners.html">Partners</a>
      </div>
      <!--dropdown-content close div-->
    </div>
    <!--dropdown close div-->
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a href="awards.html"><button class="dropbtn">Awards/Certifications</button></a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a href="services.html"><button class="dropbtn">Services</button></a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="solar.html">Solar</a>
        <a href="water.html">Water</a>
        <a href="housing.html">Housing</a>
        <a href="training.html">Training</a>
        <a href="broadband.html">Broadband</a>
      </div>
      <!--dropdown-content close div-->
    </div>
    <!--dropdown close div-->
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a href="help.html"><button class="dropbtn">How You Can Help</button></a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="donate.html">Donate</a>
        <a href="volunteer.html">Volunteer</a>
        <a href="intern.html">Intern</a>
      </div>
      <!--dropdown-content close div-->
    </div>
    <!--dropdown close div-->
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a href="contact.html"><button class="dropbtn">Contact</button></a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="email.html">Email</a>
        <a href="faqs.html">FAQS</a>
        <a href="newsletter.html">Newsletter</a>
      </div>
      <!--dropdown-content-->
    </div>
    <!--dropdown close div-->
  </div>
  <!--container close div-->
```

ps. i dont know what is up with the menu interaction, but you will know it probably.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved part of the problem and managed to get the drop-down menu to actually show every of its items on top of each other. However I didn't find how to put its sub-menu's on the side (If that's what you wanted?) and make the menu actually drop *down*. Hopefully that'll put you on the right way.

Parts of the problem came from `position` and `overflow` properties.

```css
#header {
height: 108px;
width: 1140px;
background-color: #faa220;
position: relative;
}

#Logo2 {
height: 108px;
float: left;

}

#header links {
height: 50px;
float: left;
list-style: none;
padding-top: 10px;
}

#container {
background-color: #faa220;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 215px;
}

.container a {
float: left;
font-size: 18px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
position: absolute;
}

.dropdown {
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
font-size: 18px;
border: none;
outline: none;
color: white;
padding: 14px 16px;
background-color: inherit;
cursor: pointer;
}

.container a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: #faa220;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #faa220;
min-width: 100px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
float: none;
color: white;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
/*display: block;*/
text-align: left;
position: static;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
background-color: #faa220;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
position: absolute;
display: block;
bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <img src="../JPEG/i2i logo 2.jpg" align="left" id="Logo2" />
    <div id="container">
      <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="index.html"><button class="dropbtn">Home</button></a>
        </div><!--dropdown close div-->
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="about.html"><button class="dropbtn">About Us</button></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="bio.html">Bio</a><br>
                <a href="news.html">News</a><br>
                <a href="partners.html">Partners</a>
            </div><!--dropdown-content close div-->
        </div><!--dropdown close div-->
        <div class="dropdown">  
            <a href="awards.html"><button class="dropbtn">Awards/Certifications</button></a>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="services.html"><button class="dropbtn">Services</button></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="solar.html">Solar</a><br>
                <a href="water.html">Water</a><br>
                <a href="housing.html">Housing</a><br>
                <a href="training.html">Training</a><br>
                <a href="broadband.html">Broadband</a>
            </div><!--dropdown-content close div-->
        </div><!--dropdown close div-->
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="help.html"><button class="dropbtn">How You Can Help</button></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="donate.html">Donate</a><br>
                <a href="volunteer.html">Volunteer</a><br>
                <a href="intern.html">Intern</a>
            </div><!--dropdown-content close div-->
        </div><!--dropdown close div-->
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="contact.html"><button class="dropbtn">Contact</button></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="email.html">Email</a><br>
                <a href="faqs.html">FAQS</a><br>
                <a href="newsletter.html">Newsletter</a>
            </div><!--dropdown-content-->
        </div><!--dropdown close div-->
    </div><!--container close div-->
```